# Manipulating spinner of another class's xml layout

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have a spinner with id `spinner1` in Xml layout with id `layout1` **layout1.xml is inflated by Class1.java**. I want to manipulate it from another class (**say Class2.java**) which does not inflate layout `layout1` having `spinner1`. Also, can I populate that spinner from `Class2` database column `column1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes you can if you pass the `Spinner` off to the second activity in the `Intent`. However, I am not sure if that would be a good idea (as a beginner, that's my intuition).

As for the populating with data, you can create a singleton instance of data that is shared among both the activities. Let it include an `ArrayList<>` which you use as the data for your spinner. You can then manipulate the data in the `ArrayList<>`.

Comment: Thanks @LittleChild but is there anyway that I can manipulate without passing directly from Class2.java itself.I have tried various things, but things are not working out.

Comment: @HeavenlyRavi Well you can make your variable as `static` and then use `Class1.spinnerVariable` in `Class2.java` but passing it in `Intent` seems better.